# Android Webview Input box with Qr/barcode Value insted of key input android?Not entire Webpage

Tags: javascript, android, webview, qr-code

I followed [this](https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView/blob/master/qrcodereaderview/src/main/java/com/dlazaro66/qrcodereaderview/QRCodeReaderView.java) to Read Qrcode

This is my [Webview](http://jsfiddle.net/Ua8Cv/99/)    `http://jsfiddle.net/Ua8Cv/99/`   So Here When I click on Button Or Input Box In my Webview Activity It will open My other Activity Qr reader activity... Which Is A Local Activity Out Side Webview

For that I have Given this to Open other activity Form Webivew to Myactivity Via JavaScript...

```
public class Webtest extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webc);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webm);

        WebSettings set = webView.getSettings();
        set.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        final ProgressDialog progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(Webtest.this, "Please Wait", "Loading...");

        //Enable Javascript

        // webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //Inject WebAppInterface methods into Web page by having Interface 'Android'
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "SendtoAndroid");
        webView.requestFocusFromTouch();
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()

        {
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                }
            }

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        String url = "file:///android_asset/text.html";
        try {

            if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)) {
                webView.loadUrl(url);

            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {

            String s = "<html><body style='background:#fff;'><br><div ><b><p style='color: black;font-size:20px;text-align:left;'>Unable to load information.</p></b><div style='color: black;text-align:center;'>Server May be Temporarily Down\n" + "\n" +
                    "<div style='color: black;text-align:center;'>Please Try After Sometime</p></div></div></body></html>";
        }

    }

    //Class to be injected in Web page

    public class WebAppInterface {

        Context mContext;

        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void Ma() {

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to leave to next screen?");
            // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //Move to Next screen
                            //Webtest.this.finish();

                            Intent ss = new Intent(Webtest.this, MainActivity.class);
                            ss.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                            ss.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            ss.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            ss.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                            startActivity(ss);
                        }
                    });
            // Setting Negative "NO" Button
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // Cancel Dialog
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();
        }

    }
}
```

So Till Here Every thing is Fine I can scan And Display with the above method from web-view But Here I can Able to Display the Result in my activity..

But I want to Display or add Input(my qr code value) where the cursor in My webview.. Is it possible to Give Qrcode value to Cursor in webview...

Any one please help

**Update 1**

Here I have Done with Qr/barcode and Open that Activity in Webview But I am Unable to Give Resulted Value as Input to webview  Please help me on this kind

**Update 2**

Here I am Passing My Qr code Value to `ResultA` Activity
Through Intent

Here `myval` is qr/barcode Result......

```
String udata = myval;
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ResultA.class);
    i.putExtra("sdata", udata);
    startActivity(i);
```

with This I am displaying My Output result of Qr/barcode in other Page

```
public class ResultA extends Activity {

    private static String urlString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.resu);

        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);


        String rdata;
        Intent i = getIntent();
        rdata = i.getStringExtra("sdata");

        tv.setText(tv.getText() + "\t"+ rdata + "\n");

    }

}
```

But I want the insert Same Result(**`rdata`**) in the Web-view Cursor ....

**Update 3**

I tried with this

```
    String url = "file:///android_asset/tex.html";
    webView.loadUrl(url);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    String rdata;
    Intent i = getIntent();
    rdata = i.getStringExtra("sdata");

    try {

        if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.activeElement.value = '" + rdata + "'");

        }
```

Now the Only value is showing in my page
entire page is gone...

But I want this value should be placed at the cursor (Web input box)

Please Help me...

Answer (score -2):

You can get active element from `WebView` by running `document.activeElement`. Then you need to set the value in this element from your string:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.activeElement.value = '" + yourString + "'"); //yourString is a text to be inserted into text field of the html document
```

Comment: Thanks @Vlad Matvienko Sir,  Can you check my updated Question  and  Update Your Answer with my code I am Unable to understand

Comment: @Madhu, you have to pass the value back to activity with `WebView` firstly, and then use my code to pass it to `WebView`.

Comment: @MLN, not getting what? In my answer I showed how to set some string into the field in WebView. You need to replace `yourString` with the value, you need to insert.

Comment: Ok sir I got Your Answer.. But If I give like that It just showing the result in the New webpage with value the existing page is gone ... But I want the value should be in web input box....

Comment: @MLN, will do in a min.

Comment: @MLN, meanwhile please add HTML code to your question